# My Update Command does not working

Tags: .net

```
    con.Open()
    sql = "select * from Rates where From ='" + ComboBox1.Text + "'"
    sqlcmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader
    While reader.Read
        TxtTo.Text = reader.Item("To")
        TxtRatePerTon.Text = reader.Item("RatesPerTon")
        TxtRatePerTrip.Text = reader.Item("RatesPerTrip")
    End While
    reader.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(1) = TxtDate.Text
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(2) = TxtFreightSlipNo.Text
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(3) = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(4) = TxtTo.Text
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(5) = TxtRatePerTon.Text
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(6) = TxtRatePerTrip.Text
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(7) = ComboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(8) = ComboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(9) = TxtTon.Text
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(10) = ComboBox4.SelectedValue.ToString
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(11) = TxtExtra.Text
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(12) = TxtTrips.Text
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(13) = TxtActualWeight.Text
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(14) = TxtBillWeight.Text
ds.Tables("Transport2003").Rows(inc).Item(15) = TxtAmount.Text
da.Update(ds, "Transport2003")
```

Comment: Describing the problem would be very helpful.  In what way does this fail?

Comment: When I click on Update Command then I get error "Syntax error"

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, I'm guessing that your `select` statement is invalid. `FROM` is a keyword (in SQL Server anyway), and the statement `select * from Rates where From ='` is invalid. You will get a message stating

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1  Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'from'.

To correct this, put the From in brackets, i.e `select * from Rates where [From] ='`

As a general rule, you should avoid using keynames when naming any of your database objects; it makes life easier.